# What is the etymology and basis for vehicle "license plate" in the US compared to "registration plate"?

Tags: american-english

In North America, especially the US, the term "vehicle license plate" is used to refer to vehicle *registration* plates - surely this is incorrect terminology: vehicles themselves do not have a license (that belongs to the driver), instead they have a registration - to which the text on the plate refers.

Wikipedia has a footnote in the article on US plates, but it fails to give a citation:

> The spelling *license* is preferred in the U.S.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_States#cite_note-1

(assuming they're not referring to the "license"/"licence" spelling difference).

How did this noun-misdirection happen?

Comment: The plate is, itself, a license—without it, the car can't legally be driven. Compare liquor licenses, without which an establishment can't legally serve alcohol. The main difference is that bars and restaurants are generally stationary, so the license can conveniently be a piece of paper on an interior wall rather than a metal plate affixed to the exterior. Note that the license to drive is separate from the car's license to be driven. The former depends on proven driving skill, knowledge, and record of safe driving; the latter on payment of required fees and insurance.

Comment: To add to 1006a's comment, in addition to the vehicle's license, which deals with things such as whether it meets standards, it also has a registration.  The registration deals with the vehicle's ownership.  The registration is designated by stickers that go on the license plate.  Your Wikipedia link has a "registration plate" title, but explains the detail in the body.  The terminology dates back to the early days of automobiles, and isn't quite consistent with current practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can trace the terminology back to 1898, when the city of Chicago enacted a Wheel Tax on vehicles and called it a license to operate vehicles on public streets. Naturally, someone took issue with having to pay the associated fee, and the Illinois Supreme Court decided in favor of the city in [*City of Chicago v Collins*](https://casetext.com/case/city-of-chicago-v-collins), 175 Ill. 445 (Ill. 1898) deciding that with the power granted the City Council to regulate the streets

> the implied power is conferred to require a **license** to use the streets....

The Court even helpfully calls upon a source to define the word *license*:

> A license is a privilege granted by the State, usually on payment of a valuable consideration

The license granted upon registration, the permission for a vehicle to be present on public property, is not associated with a car's driver, as you claim -- that's a different license, the permission to drive on public streets -- but with the vehicle itself. Owners have to pay the fee, but separately for every vehicle they own.

So the answer to your question is that the terminology goes back to the dawn of vehicle licensure but isn't a misapplication of the word *license*.